# Appending a Parameter to URL upon form submission, based on a selection box Value

Tags: php, forms, url, search

I'm trying to build a custom search form using PHP and I'm looking for a way to append a parameter to the end of the URL (based on a selection from a selection box), upon form submission.

Say I have a selection box with these values:
`Red Blue Green`

If I choose 'Blue' and submit the form, I want the URL to be:

`http://customsearch.com/result/?Blue`

Thank you for any help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could (1) rewrite the submission URL dynamically from the form entries using JavaScript (as suggested by @roselan above), (2) implement rewrite rules (in .htaccess, for example) or (3) process the form field entries (via POST) on the submission page and use a simple URL redirect like this:

```
/** This is the script the form submits to **/

// Assuming a single dropdown field, set the values of the options to match
// whatever you want sent in the URL, and then submit them via POST.
//
// For a value of "Blue" in the form field where "name='dropdown_name'", the
// following will redirect to:
//   http://customsearch.com/result/?Blue
header( "Location: http://customsearch.com/result/?" . $_POST['dropdown_name'] );
```

Comment: thank you Andrew, I can't seem to see Roselan's post above though. I will probably end up doing 1 or 3, I have a feeling this could get messy with htaccess

Answer (score 1):

Then you need a mixture of [`$_GET[]`](http://www.google.com.ng/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=%24_get&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CCMQFjAA&url=http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php&ei=6ISxTqqvKsfssga1-vQ9&usg=AFQjCNHF-g0UEkXh5Zf9CGnieUs-jU2HHQ) and [.htaccess](http://www.google.com.ng/search?gcx=w&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=.htaccess%20search)